# How to access/login to neo4j browser from web application built on React

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, react-redux

How to access Neo4j Browser url from a react application on a button click event which automatically logs in to the url by providing Connect URL, Username & Password

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to access `Neo4j server` OR `Neo4j browser` from your React App?

Comment: Neo4j Browser url, on click of a button/hyperlink I need to open Neo4j browser url in a new tab and automatically login to the server/database by providing the following inputs Connect URL, Username & Password from react app.